# Symfony downloads the Apache server after logging

Tags: apache, symfony, symfony4

I am using symfony 4 and configure the login this works fine but at the time of login the apache server falls and I have to restart to make it work but if I go to another link it falls back.

this is my configuration

```
//.env
APP_ENV=dev
APP_DEBUG=0
```

And other archive:

```
//security.yaml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Usuario: bcrypt

    providers:
        user_db:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Usuario
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            #pattern:   ^/
            #anonymous: ~
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                login_path:  login
                check_path:  login_check
                #check_path:  login
                #default_target_path: app
                provider: user_db
                remember_me: true
            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: app
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: You problably have an error message in symfony log (var/log/dev.log) or in your apache log. This message will help us to help you :)

Comment: Maybe you'll need to add the .htaccess file contained in symfony/apache-pack recipe with `composer req  symfony/apache-pack` recipe  https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/symfony/apache-pack ? 

It's not included by defautl anymore if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Try another machine and the problem is solved, do not make any changes, I already had the apache-pack installed. I'm going to restart the machine and reinstall the project to see if the problem is solved.